# Insert numpy array that contains a subarray to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, numpy, psycopg2

I have a numpy array that needs to be inserted to PostgreSQL. The numpy array is that contains the subarray is already in a tuple.
The tuple looks something like this:

((1,0., -0.5, [0, 0], 1, 5)). - I've shortened the array to show the subarray.

The tuple contains a single item to insert a single row. If I wanted to insert multiple rows, the tuple would containe multiple items.

I have registered PostgreSQL adapters for numpy.uint32, numpy.float32 and numpy.ndarray.:

```py
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs

def numpy2pyUInt32(self,npUInt32):
    return AsIs(npUInt32.item())
def numpy2pyFloat32(self,npFloat32):
    return AsIs(npFloat32.item())
def numpy2pyndarray(self,npndarray):
    return AsIs(npndarray.tolist())

register_adapter(numpy.uint32, self.numpy2pyUInt32)
register_adapter(numpy.float32, self.numpy2pyFloat32)
register_adapter(numpy.ndarray, self.numpy2pyndarray)
```

To insert the data, I'm using `execute_values()` with following sql command:
`INSERT INTO mytable VALUES %s`. But when I execute this I get an error from psycopg2 saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "...", line 132, in <module>  
    ...
  File "...", line 113, in ...
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values (cur, sql_command, col_values)
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1292, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...06346473842859,0.0,0.0,0.0,14.284889221191406,4,0,[0, 0],540...
                                                             ^
```

Additional info:

```
data = ((1,0., -0.5, ..., [0, 0], 1, 5))
print(type(data)) # <class 'tuple'>
print(type(data[0])) # <class 'numpy.void'>
print(data[0].dtype) #
[('..', '<u4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'),
 ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f8'), ('..', '<f4'),
 ('..', '<f4'), ('..', '<f4'), ('..', 'u1'), ('..', 'u1'),
 ('..', 'u1',(2,)), # sub-array
 ('..', '<u4'), ('..', '<u4'), ('..', '<u4'), ('..', '<u4'), ('..', '<u4'), 
 ('..', '<u4')]
print (data[0].shape) # ()
print (type(data[0][0])) # <class 'numpy.uint32'>
...
print (type(data[0][14])) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Post the full trace back. Right now it looks like the error is in you `AsIs` function

Comment: (side note, that's a list in your tuple. not a numpy array)

Comment: @PaulH the AsIs function is from `psycopg2`: `from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs`

Comment: @PaulH I got the numpy array from an HDF5 file using h5py. I opened a dataset (ds) and called `tuple(ds[0:1])`

Comment: just to clarify what Paul was saying: a tuple containing a numpy array would look like this:

`(1,0., -0.5, array([0, 0]), 1, 5)`

but `((1,0., -0.5, [0, 0], 1, 5))` is a tuple of a tuple containing a *list*. it may just be the notation you wrote to represent the example. print it out and maybe interrogate the `type(list_or_array_element)`

Comment: I added output from `print(type())` calls to different elements in the tuple.

Comment: Show `data[0].dtype`.  Also `data[0].shape`.  You/we need a clear idea of what this tuple and array are.  May be you should step back and look a `ds`.  Again, `dtype` and `shape`.  Indexing `ds` with the slice, and then wrapping it in `tuple` may be obscuring vital information.

Comment: @hpaulj I have added `data[0].dtype` and `data[0].shape`. `ds` is returned from `h5py` module that I wrap with a `tuple()` call to send to PostgreSQL.

Comment: That's a compound dtype and `arr = ds[:]` is a `structured array`.  One of the fields has size 2.

Answer (score 0):

Define a dtype:

```
In [16]: dt=np.dtype([('x','f'),('y','i',2)])
```

and structured array:

```
In [17]: arr = np.zeros(3,dt)
In [18]: arr
Out[18]: 
array([(0., [0, 0]), (0., [0, 0]), (0., [0, 0])],
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<i4', (2,))])
```

Looking at one record:

```
In [19]: arr[0]
Out[19]: (0., [0, 0])
```

wrapping that in tuple does not convert that inner array:

```
In [20]: tuple(arr[0])
Out[20]: (0.0, array([0, 0], dtype=int32))
In [21]: print(tuple(arr[0]))
(0.0, array([0, 0], dtype=int32))
In [22]: arr[0].tolist()
Out[22]: (0.0, array([0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

Focusing on that one field:

```
In [23]: arr['y']
Out[23]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=int32)
In [24]: arr['y'][0]
Out[24]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [25]: arr['y'].tolist()
Out[25]: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Indexing the array using a list of field names minus the problem one:

```
In [26]: arr[['x']]
Out[26]: 
array([(0.,), (0.,), (0.,)],
      dtype={'names':['x'], 'formats':['<f4'], 'offsets':[0], 'itemsize':12})
In [27]: tuple(arr[['x']][0])
Out[27]: (0.0,)
In [29]: arr[['x']].tolist()
Out[29]: [(0.0,), (0.0,), (0.0,)]
```

Comment: I did call the `.tolist()` method in my adapter for PostgreSQL as stated in the code in the question but looks like psycopg2 didn't handle it correctly?

Comment: Notice in `OUT[22]` that the `tolist` doesn't touch that inner array.

Comment: I was looking at out `OUT[25]`. The adapter registered with PostgreSQL is for type `numpy.ndarray`. And I put a print statement in the adapter that I've registered and it does get called with the correct `[0, 0]` which is the same data that PostgreSQL error message points to.